# How to compile wxWidgets for x64 on Windows?

Tags: visual-c++, build, wxwidgets

I have had quite the experience trying to compile wxWidgets on Windows for x64. After a nightmare setting up Visual C++ 2008 express to compile x64 apps, I opened the wx.sln file. (I'm using wxWidgets 2.9.0, by the way.) I picked the Release configuration and set x64 as the platform. When I hit build, I get a slew of errors saying that wx/setup.h is missing. It would seem like the file is not being created. The real mystery is that the above steps work perfectly for wxWidgets 2.8.10. Any idea why this does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you have the file include/wx/msw/setup.h (in particular, it wouldn't be there if you checked sources out of svn). Other than that also check that you use vc9 versions of the project files just to be sure that you don't run into some import problems. With these projects all the necessary setup.h under lib/vc_lib (or vc_dll) directory should be created automatically by custom build steps in the projects.

Comment: Ah yes. That was it. I was opening the old VC6 solution instead of the VC9 one.